# MVVM Light - PivotControl

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm starting to develop a WP7 app with MVVM Light. I want to make use of the pivot control to show two different lists of different item types. Would it be best practice to create the PivotItems as UserControls or should I stick everything in one viewmodel?

Answer (score 4):

I think there is no "correct" way to do it, it just depends on your vision.

Personnally, I always create separate UserControls to act as PivotItems.

The main objective is to make my code clearer, with more separate classes it is way more easily unserstandable!
However it also depends on the complexity of the items. Don't feel forced to create one UserControl per item, just separate if the control is quite complex and requires quite a lot of XAML lines, it will clarify your code